# Passing a string variable (querying by username) to a mongoose query function (find) - doesn't seem to work

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'll be glad for some help, thanks in advance :)

```
export async function serviceGetPostsByUsername(username) {
    const allPosts = await PostModel.find({author: username})
    return allPosts
```

in Postman JSON I get:

```
[]
```

However, when I'm doing that :

```
export async function serviceGetPostsByUsername(username){
    const allPosts = await PostModel.find({author: username})
    return allPosts
```

I get the data I asked for.

I checked the type of username I have passed to the function (it's a string), and I tried to use a string literal as a value but it doesn't seem to work.

Here's the model of the collection:

```
const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    author: {type: String, ref:"User", required: true, index: true},
    body: { type: String, required: true, validate: (value) => { value.length > 0 } },
    likes: { type: Number, default: 0},
    caption: {type: String},
    comments: {type: JSON},
    mediaList: {type: []},
    created: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})

export const PostModel = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema)
```

Comment: On the first example you used `{author: username}`, but on the second example you used: `{username: 'sasuke1'}`. Why did you change `author` to `username`?

Comment: Why the change from `PostModel.find(...` to `UserModel.findOne(...`?

Comment: I was confused by accident but the problem is the same. my intention was to share: 

export async function serviceGetPostsByUsername(username){
    const allPosts = await PostModel.find({author: 'sasuke1'})
    console.log(typeof(username))
    return allPosts